# ログ収集でGETのqueryパラメータを取得しjsonにパースする方法がわかりません、、

Tags: json, apache, fluentd

apacheのアクセスログをfluentdで収集して、s3に保存しRedShiftに蓄積したいのですが、
GETのクエリ文字列部分の取り出し方がわからず苦戦しております。（jsonにパースしたい）

例） 
//hogehoge.co.jp/test.php?test_id=111&param=hoge

apacheのLogFormatで%qを指定し、"?test_id=111&param=hoge"までは取得できており、
fluentdではltsv形式にしているので、通常のログはjson化できています。
（現状、path:"?test_id=111&param=hoge"になっている）

これを、path:{"test_id:111","param":"hoge"}のjsonの形にパースしたいのですが、やり方がわかりません。。。

どなたかご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: `"test_id:111","param":"hoge"` だけなら tail プラグインの format の正規表現で実現出来そうですが それでは目的果たしませんか？ [こんな感じ](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/parse?regexp=%28%3F%3Cpath%3E%28%3F%3Ctest_id%3Etest_id%3D[0-9]%2B%29%26%28%3F%3Cparam%3Eparam%3D.%2B%29%29&input=%2F%2Fhogehoge.co.jp%2Ftest.php%3Ftest_id%3D111%26param%3Dhoge&time_format=)になりました。